# cp: target '/path/to/directory' is not a directory

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I really confused by `target /path/to/directory is not a directory` when i want to copying all files in `build/*` to the direction in by this rule in `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
 script:

    - cp -rf build/* /path/to/directory
```

I've also check this command by removing/adding `/` at end and start of the destination but won't help.

**Note:** it's OK when i manually run the cp command in server terminal and have no problem with it.This command was successful when i run it manually through terminal in ubuntu server.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: Make the directory first. This is just running a sh command so the problem is definitely on your end.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I just put `whoami` on top of the script tag and it is now working :)

Answer (score 1):

> it's OK when i manually run the cp command in server terminal and have no problem with it.

That is probably because the target folder exists in the server itself, while it might not exist in the context of the GitLab runner.

You should either:

- create the target folder:

  ```
  mkdir -p /path/to/directory
  ```
- or [mount the server target folder as a data volume](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#example-2-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

  ```
  volumes = ["/path/to/bind/from/host:/path/to/bind/in/container:rw"]
  ```

Comment: i have run the `mkdir -p /path/to/directory` but it now says `Permission denied`.

Comment: @Aly Then do a `ls -alrth /path/to` (parent folder of the directory to create), as well as a `id -a`, to understand who you are (when the runner executes your script) and what permission needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar error because one of my files had a space in its name and so the path it was looking for was only reading the string after the space.